PyLTSpice "SimRunner" function not working
I'm using VSCode with Python 3.11.0 in a virtual enviroment. I installed in an enviroment pip install PyLTSpice==4.0.3.
However, it doesn't seem to work and I can't find out why (I'm quite new to python programming). I attach here the real code and the traceback for a circuit drawn in LTspice and that I tried to run its simulation with PyLTspice.
The code is:

from PyLTSpice import RawRead
from PyLTSpice import SimRunner
from PyLTSpice import SpiceEditor
from PyLTSpice import LTspice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

simulator =  r"C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\XVIIx64.exe"

LTC_runner = SimRunner(os.path.dirname(__file__))
LTC_runner.create_netlist(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'\LTZ1000_7V_1.asc')
netlist = SpiceEditor(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'\LTZ1000_7V_1.net')

print('LTC created')
print()
print(LTC_runner)
print("netlist created:",netlist)

netlist.add_instructions(
    "; Simulation settings",
    ".param run = 0"  
)

netlist.reset_netlist()    
netlist.add_instructions(  
    "; Simulation settings",
    ".save V(Vz_out)",
   ".meas out PARAM V(Vz_out) ; final value of V(out)"
)

rawfile, logfile = LTC_runner.run(netlist)  # Runs the simulation with the updated netlist

LTC_runner.wait_completion()

print('Successful/Total Simulations: ' + str(LTC_runner.okSim) + '/' + str(LTC_runner.runno))


The traceback log:

    SimRunner started
Using LTspice installed in : 'C:\Program Files\LTC\LTspiceXVII\XVIIx64.exe'
Creating Netlist
OK
LTC created
<PyLTSpice.sim.sim_runner.SimRunner object at 0x000002781FE1CC10>
netlist created: <PyLTSpice.sim.spice_editor.SpiceEditor object at 0x0000027829A9DF90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\LTZ1000_Sims\LTZ1000_1_sim2.py", line 53, in 
LTC_runner.run(netlist)
File "C:\Users\jsuarez\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\PyLTSpice\sim\sim_runner.py", line 351, in run
if (wait_resource is False) or (self.active_threads() < self.parallel_sims):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

I guess that it actually finds the ".asc" LTSpice model file, but at some point it misses something but I could not figure out what is it. I do not know why this TypeError is caused fo netlist parameter. Thanks in advance!
